# Gson deserializing nested objects with InstanceCreator

Tags: java, android, gson

I have a class named `PageItem`, which has a constructor that takes a `Context` as parameter:

```
PageItem(Context context)
{
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
}
```

`PageItem` has these properties:

```
private int id; 
private String Title; 
private String Description; 
public Newsprovider newsprovider; 
public Topic topic;
```

`Newsprovider` and `Topic` are other classes of my application and have the following constructors:

```
Newsprovider (Context context)
{
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
}

Topic (Context context)
{
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
}
```

`PageItem`, `Newsprovider` and `Topic` are subclasses of `SQLiteOpenHelper`.

I want to deserialize `PageItem` array with Gson, so I wrote:

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(PageItem.class, new PageItemInstanceCreator(context));
Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
Pageitem pis[] = gson.fromJson(s, PageItem[].class);
```

with `PageItemInstanceCreator` defined as:

```
public class PageItemInstanceCreator implements InstanceCreator<PageItem>
    {
        private Context context;

        public PageItemInstanceCreator(Context context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public PageItem createInstance(Type type)
        {
            PageItem pi = new PageItem(context);
            return pi; 
        }
}
```

When debugging, a `PageItem` instance has correctly "MainActivity" as context while 
but its `newsprovider` member variable has context = null.

Gson created `PageItem` object using the right constructor but it created `Newsprovider` instance using the default parameterless constructor. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just add a new `InstanceCreator` derived class for `NewsProvider` like this:

```
public class NewsProviderInstanceCreator implements InstanceCreator<NewsProvider>
    {
        private int context;

        public NewsProviderInstanceCreator(int context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public NewsProvider createInstance(Type type)
        {
            NewsProvider np = new NewsProvider(context);
            return np; 
        }

}
```

and register it into the `GsonBuilder` like you have already done, like this:

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(PageItem.class, new PageItemInstanceCreator(context));
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(NewsProvider.class, new NewsProviderInstanceCreator(context));
Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
PageItem pis[] = gson.fromJson(s, PageItem[].class);
```

repeat it also for `Topic` class.